# Two outputs for the same SQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm developing facebook extension for cscart that publishes items to facebook using cron. On my local dev env: wamp Apache 2.2.22/PHP 5.3.13/MySQL 5.6.14 the query produces desired output which it's one row, but when i test the same query on my hosting it produces the same row multiple times. I just couldn't figure it out.
My hosting env: MySQL 5.5.33-31.1
Query:

```
SELECT  s.product_id
     ,    category
     ,    product
     ,    short_description
     ,    full_description
     , pd.meta_keywords
     ,  p.status
     ,  p.approved
     , il.image_id
     , il.pair_id
     , il.object_type 
  FROM cscart_social s
  LEFT 
  JOIN cscart_products p
    ON p.product_id = s.product_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cscart_product_descriptions pd
    ON s.product_id = pd.product_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cscart_products_categories pc
    ON s.product_id = pc.product_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cscart_category_descriptions cd
    ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cscart_images_links il
    ON il.object_id = s.product_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cscart_images i
    ON cscart_images.image_id = il.pair_id 
 WHERE 0 IN (fb_publish,tw_publish);
```

Comment: Add a group by cscart_social.product_id to your Query.

Comment: Does your dev server use a literal dump from the production database? It's possible that they actually have different row counts for the same query and need to be grouped (as mentioned above).

Comment: @1linecode, Nathan Cox, thanks that worked!
But i couldn't get it yet. Why the different output for the same tables structure either on  local env or live env?

Comment: maybe its based on your env settings or data in your tables are not the same, so it returns different rows.

Comment: Be careful with the [MySQL Extension to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). As the docs explain, it's non-standard, plus it was implemented for optimization, not for getting rid of multiple identical rows. If you're really getting the same row multiple times - every column with an identical value - use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead as it's standard SQL. Better yet, review all the tables in the query, find the ones with duplicate rows, and clean them up - if not you'll probably have trouble with other queries.

Comment: It's frustrating that GROUP BY typically performs faster than DISTINCT as that's clearly not its primary purpose. :-(

Comment: Some observations: 1. Properly qualify ALL columns - it makes it SO much easier (for us) to read (and use table aliases for this). 2. fb_publish and tw_publish belong to the social table, right? 3. Do you actually select any columns from the images table?

Answer (score -1):

Here are the two solutions:

1. I think you forgot to add a INNER JOIN condition with the query.
2. The best way to avoid duplicate record is to use DISTINCT.